# Running Hadoop in Windows 7 setting via Cygwin - PriviledgedActionException as:PC cause:java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path:

Tags: hadoop, cygwin

I use Hadoop distribution 1.1.2. When I try to run example wordcount routine I get following error.

Input command:

> 'D:/Files/hadoop-1.1.2/hadoop-1.1.2/bin/hadoop' jar 'D:/Files/hadoop-1.1.2/hadoop-1.1.2/hadoop-examples-1.1.2.jar' wordcount input output

The result:

> 13/07/03 11:02:42 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>   13/07/03 11:02:42 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:PC cause:java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-PC\mapred\staging\PC119237705.staging to 0700
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-PC\mapred\staging\PC119237705.staging to 0700
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:689)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:662)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:509)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:344)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:189)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:116)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:918)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:912)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:912)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:500)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:530)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:67)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:64)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)

I have problem to locate the particular cause of this error. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have hit [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7682). You might find this [patch](https://github.com/congainc/patch-hadoop_7682-1.0.x-win) helpful. But, before that you might wanna try changing the directory permissions to 755 and re-running the job.

Comment: I'v tried to use this patch - it didn't work. Cygwin environment is rather new to me. How do I change the directory permissions?

Comment: sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/directory..BTW, why do you want to do this on Win? It's always a pain.

Comment: To be honest I though it's less painfull. I guess that finally I'll switch to some variant of Linux.

Comment: By the way, which Linux distribution is the most suitable to handle Hadoop?

Comment: There is no limitation as such. I am using Ubuntu on my laptop and it works just perfect.